# Number of ways to arrange three 1s, two 2s, two 3s and one 4?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, multinomial-coefficients

Number of ways to arrange three 1s, two 2s, two 3s and one 4? The order doesn't matter.

The direct answer from the book is $\frac{8!}{3!2!2!1!}$, but is there another way to do it?

Comment: Choose three of the eight positions of the 1s, two of the remaining five positions for the 2s, two of the remaining three positions for the 3s, and place the 4 in the only remaining position.  Of course, the order matters.  Otherwise, it would not be an arrangement.

Comment: Supplying the math behind the comment of @N.F.Taussig, the equivalent formulation is $\binom{8}{3} \times \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{1}{1}.$  The (**equivalent**) original formula is (**perhaps**) based on the intuition that if you start with an estimate of $(8!)$, you then have to adjust for the over-counting of the $1$s, $2$s, and $3$s.  The denominator is thus construed to be the required adjustments re over-counting.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an  iterative approach to find the number of ways to arrange three $1$s, two $2$s, two $3$s and one $4$:

- **Three $1$s:** We start with three $1$s:
  \begin{align*}
  1\ 1\ 1\qquad\rightarrow\quad 1\ \mathrm{way}\quad
  \end{align*}
- **Two $2$s:** We have now $4$ positions where we can place two $2$s. We have $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to place  two $2\mathrm{s}$ at one position and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to place two $2$s at different positions:
  \begin{align*}
  \bullet\ 1\ \bullet\ 1\ \bullet\ 1\ \bullet \qquad\rightarrow\quad \binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}\ \mathrm{ways}
  \end{align*}
- **Two $3$s:** To each of the valid arrangements consisting of three $1$s and two $2$s we have now $6$ positions where we can place two $3$s. We habe $\binom{6}{1}$ ways to place two $3$s at one position and $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to place two $3\mathrm{s}$ at different positions:
  \begin{align*}
  \bullet\ 1\ \bullet\ 1\ \bullet\ 2\ \bullet\ 1\ \bullet\ 2\ \bullet \qquad\rightarrow\quad \binom{6}{1}+\binom{6}{2}\ \mathrm{ways}\quad\qquad\quad
  \end{align*}
- **One $4$:** To each of the valid arrangements consisting of three $1$s, two $2$s and two $3$s we have now $\binom{8}{1}$ positions to place the number $4$.
  \begin{align*}
  \bullet\ 1\ \bullet\ 1 \bullet\ 3 \bullet\ 3\ \bullet\ 2\ \bullet\ 1\ \bullet\ 2\ \bullet \qquad\rightarrow\quad \binom{8}{1}\ \mathrm{ways}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad
  \end{align*}

> We conclude: The number of valid arrangements is
> \begin{align*}
> &1\cdot \left[\binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}\right]\cdot\left[ \binom{6}{1}+\binom{6}{2}\right]\cdot\binom{8}{1}\\
> &\qquad=\binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{2}8=10\cdot21\cdot 8\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=1\,680}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with $\frac{8!}{3!2!2!1!}=1\,680$.

Here we use the binomial identity $\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}$.